# base_url() function not working in codeigniter.

Tags: base-url

"> Home (current)

Error:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Call to undefined function base_url()
Filename:views/home.php

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you share code also. Now try following code, It will work for you.

```
redirect(base_url().'action');
```

It will redirect at your desire action.